# Mysql sales table grouped by customer and displayed by month columns pivot query

Tags: mysql, database, pivot-table

I have a **sales** table with the following columns:

```
|  Customer_Id | amount |  date  |
```

What would be the best way to group data by `customer_id`, and displaying  monthly total(SUM) of amount for each Customer_id (one row per Customer_id), on distinct month columns?

The desired output would be something like:

```
Customer     |January    | February   | March       | ....

Customer_id  |SUM amount | SUM amount | SUM amount | ....
```

I believe in Sql this is called a pivot table.

¡Thanks!

Comment: Do you try anything?

Comment: This is often done with the grouping as in most of the answers and then column that use `case` expressions. `sum(case when month(date) = 1 then amount else null end) as January, ...`

Comment: Generally, for reasons of scalability and flexibility, issues of data display are best handled in application level code (e.g. PHP) if such a thing is available.

Comment: @shawnt00 How could I use sum(case when mont... and have results displayed only ONE row per customer_id?

Comment: You probably didn't add a `GROUP BY Customer_id` which by definition gets you ONE row per customer_id.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's say you have following table:

```
mysql> select * from sales;
+-------------+--------+------------+
| customer_id | amount | date       |
+-------------+--------+------------+
|           1 |     12 | 2015-01-01 |
|           1 |      1 | 2015-01-02 |
|           1 |    663 | 2015-02-12 |
|           2 |     22 | 2015-01-03 |
|           2 |     21 | 2015-02-12 |
|           2 |     11 | 2015-02-12 |
|           2 |      9 | 2015-04-12 |
+-------------+--------+------------+
```

You can do this using this query:

```
SELECT
  customer_id,
  sum(if(month(date) = 1, amount, 0))  AS Jan,
  sum(if(month(date) = 2, amount, 0))  AS Feb,
  sum(if(month(date) = 3, amount, 0))  AS Mar,
  sum(if(month(date) = 4, amount, 0))  AS Apr,
  sum(if(month(date) = 5, amount, 0))  AS May,
  sum(if(month(date) = 6, amount, 0))  AS Jun,
  sum(if(month(date) = 7, amount, 0))  AS Jul,
  sum(if(month(date) = 8, amount, 0))  AS Aug,
  sum(if(month(date) = 9, amount, 0))  AS Sep,
  sum(if(month(date) = 10, amount, 0)) AS Oct,
  sum(if(month(date) = 11, amount, 0)) AS Nov,
  sum(if(month(date) = 12, amount, 0)) AS `Dec`
FROM sales
GROUP BY customer_id;
```

And the output:

```
+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| customer_id | Jan  | Feb  | Mar  | Apr  | May  | Jun  | Jul  | Aug  | Sep  | Oct  | Nov  | Dec  |
+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|           1 |   13 |  663 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|           2 |   22 |   32 |    0 |    9 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: Great answer! But how could I have the output display just ONE ROW for each distinct customer_id?

Comment: Get rid of the grouping on `month(date)`. The sum+case I wrote about in comments above is the standard SQL way to do this but otherwise I think they're equivalent.

Comment: @helloworld I edited my post, now return correct data.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT `Customer_id` AS Customer,
SUM(`amount`) AS MONTHNAME(`date`)
FROM `sales`
GROUP BY YEAR(`date`), MONTH(`date`);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't have distinct sales value columns for each month. I`m trying to create them from the date field.

Comment: Provide the table structure.

Comment: Three columns: |  Customer_Id | amount |  date  |

Answer (score 1):

MySQL provides the WITH ROLLUP modifier for the GROUP BY clause. [Take a look at this.](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/mysql/w/wiki/6349.pivoting)

`... 
GROUP BY customer_id WITH ROLLUP`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

SELECT `Customer_id`, SUM(amount), MONTHNAME(date)
FROM `sales_table`
GROUP BY MONTH(date);

Comment: Thanks! But this query does not provide the sum for each Customer_id, but it does group the total amount for the month.

Comment: Try adding GROUP BY MONTH(date), Customer_id

Comment: Thanks but not exactly what I´m looking for

Answer (score 0):

This query gets the desired result:

```
SELECT Customer_id,

Sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 1 THEN amount END) AS Jan,
Sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 2 THEN amount END) AS Feb,
Sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 3 THEN amount END) AS Mar,
...

FROM table_name

GROUP BY Customer_id
```

Thanks to @shawnt00 for the heads up ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you change each line like this in the answer from Piotr

```
sum(if(month(date) = 1, amount, 0))  AS Jan,
```

to

```
sum(if((month(date) = 1 AND year(date) = 2017 ),  amount,0))  AS Jan_17,
```

you can split the table when there is more than a year of data

Comment: If you want to add a small change to an already accepted answer, try editing the answer, instead of adding a new answer. People usually only look at the first answer, maybe second, so it's very unlikely that they will notice your suggestion. When editing an answer, it's probably best is if you add your suggestion at the very end, and indicate it's an addition